# Authorize with Permissions

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

I've done the "Getting Started with an ASP.NET MVC 3 Website" using Facebook C# SDK 5.0.8. Everything works fine.

How do I request extra Permissions from the user after that?

When I do `[Authorize(Permissions = "offline_access")]`, I get 'System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute' does not contain a definition for 'Permissions' error.

If I use `[FacebookAuthorize(Permissions = "offline_access")]`, the page redirects to itself without going to the facebook login page.

Please help!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the Authorize attribute is not part of the Facebook C# SDK. That example show you how to use Facebook authorization in conjunction with Forms authorization. The Authorize attribute does not contain a property named permission nor could it be used to authorize with Facebook, it is checking for permissions using your current ASP.NET Membership provider.

Regarding the FacebookAuthorize attribute not working, that is because you can't mix the two scenarios together. Basically, the tutorial you read shows you how to do authorization in the most simple way without using the Javascript SDK, etc. You should not use anything in Facebook.Web or Facebook.Web.Mvc in that tutorial as they are not designed to work with Forms Authentication.

I would suggest taking a look at some of the other samples. YThey will help you get started for some of the more common scenarios like asking for additional permissions.

Comment: Thanks Nathan!

May be it's just me but I can't find any samples regarding MVC Authentication from the samples folder downloaded from the site or under the documentation section on the site. There is an "Authentication Examples" page on the site but it's empty.
 
Is that possible to direct me to a couple of example pages? 
 
Many thanks

Comment: I just posted another tutorial. You should take a look at it, I think it is more what you will need. http://bit.ly/dSeX8I

Answer (score 4):

I've got it!

This is what I need to do under "LogOn" action to request extra permission:

```
var loginUri = oAuthClient.GetLoginUrl(new Dictionary<string, object> { { "state", returnUrl }, { "scope", "offline_access" } });
```

Comment: if you need both user_photos and friend_photos, which are both under scope parameter, how is your code modified?

Comment: @Ryan - use a comma delimited approach with all your permissions. For example: { "scope", "manage_pages, publish_stream" }